# Webgl texture interlaced flickering on dedicated GPU

Tags: javascript, graphics, opengl-es, webgl, flicker

I have a vertex buffer object that contains all vertices for an array of surface objects. Each object can use a different texture, up to 16 for my browser supports up to 16 only. My problem is I get interlaced flickering on most surfaces, while some others not.

Here's my fragment shader :

`precision mediump float;
    varying vec2 texCoord;
    varying float texNum;

    uniform sampler2D texture0;
    uniform sampler2D texture1;
    uniform sampler2D texture2;
    uniform sampler2D texture3;
    uniform sampler2D texture4;
    uniform sampler2D texture5;
    uniform sampler2D texture6;
    uniform sampler2D texture7;
    uniform sampler2D texture8;
    uniform sampler2D texture9;
    uniform sampler2D texture10;
    uniform sampler2D texture11;
    uniform sampler2D texture12;
    uniform sampler2D texture13;
    uniform sampler2D texture14;
    uniform sampler2D texture15;

    void main(void){
        if(texNum == 0.0){
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture0,texCoord);
        }else if(texNum == 1.0){
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture1,texCoord);
        }else if(texNum == 2.0){
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture2,texCoord);
        }else if(texNum == 3.0){
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture3,texCoord);
        }else if(texNum == 4.0){
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture4,texCoord);
        }else if(texNum == 5.0){
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture5,texCoord);
        }else if(texNum == 6.0){
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture6,texCoord);
        }else if(texNum == 7.0){
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture7,texCoord);
        }else if(texNum == 8.0){
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture8,texCoord);
        }else if(texNum == 9.0){
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture9,texCoord);
        }else if(texNum == 10.0){
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture10,texCoord);
        }else if(texNum == 11.0){
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture11,texCoord);
        }else if(texNum == 12.0){
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture12,texCoord);
        }else if(texNum == 13.0){
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture13,texCoord);
        }else if(texNum == 14.0){
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture14,texCoord);
        }else if(texNum == 15.0){
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture15,texCoord);
        }

        if(gl_FragColor.a < 0.1) discard;
    }`

A picture of what is happening :
[image]

Now, here's the deal. This works perfectly on a machine with **intel hd integrated graphics**; not any flickering. This only happens when I run it on my desktop with **gtx 770 dedicated gpu.**

Why? How?

Comment: try using high precision and/or casting to an integer

Comment: @LJ Thank you very much for that. This did not fix my problem but you gave me a path to search on. I will post my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution :
the problem was from the float equality comparison which was resulting to false most of the time because of the float precision margin errors of my GPU.

All I had to do was to test if the difference between my texNum and the immediate texture number was smaller than a margin of error of 0.00001 called epsilon.

In code, I replaced all float equality comparison, for example, the first one:

```
if(texNum == 0.0){
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture0,texCoord);
}
```

For this :

```
if((texNum - 0.0) < 0.00001){
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture0,texCoord);
}
```